# Changes made to derived classes by declaring virtual in base class

Tags: c++

I am writing a safari class from my current OOP course. The safari has tigers, lions, and giraffes. The animals are derived from base class Animal. Now, I supposed to implement a CountTigers routine. However, I am supposed to do this "without changing" the lion and giraffe classes. This project has many other aspects (GUI, animal deletion, menus etc., mouse events) -  some I may be able to do this inadvertently.

Now, the CountTigers routine should be included in the Safari class, which has a list of all the animals within the safari. My goal was to iterate through the list of animals, and to check if the current Animal is a Tiger and return a value representing the number of Tigers. I can do this easily by including a virtual function in my Animals class and implementing it only in the Tigers class.

```
Class Animal:
  ....
  virtual bool IsTiger();

Class Tiger: public Animal
  ....
  virtual bool IsTiger(return true;)
```

I can now iterate through the list of animals and check IsTiger on each animal. My question is, because I have declared a virtual function in Animal, am I "changing" the giraffe and lion classes even without implementing the virtual function?

Comment: The answer depends entirely on the exact definition your teacher assigns to the word "changing".

Comment: If you're not providing a default implementation in `Animal` (and you haven't here), then yes, you're definitely changing *something*, because the code will no longer link. Either declare it pure-virtual and provide implementation in *all* end-derivations, or provide a default implementation in `Animal` (which returns `false`) and provide an override in `Tiger` (which returns `true`).

Comment: I was almost going to suggest an approach passing a `std::type_info const &` and comparing typeids...

Comment: Would proving a default implementation still mean that I am changing the other two animal classes despite those two classes lacking implementations? My only other approach was to try and get the .png name of the image associated with the wxImage or wxBitmap objects associated with the objects, but cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: It's a very wide ranging safari that includes lions and tigers.

Comment: @john and bears, oh my!

Comment: ...i know this is not the thing your teacher is looking for, but `Animal* animal_ptr; int tiger_count = 0; if (dynamic_cast<Tiger*>(animal_ptr)) tiget_count++;`

Comment: Decorator wrapping the Tiger class?

Comment: My best guess is that "without changing" means not modifying the source. Therefore I would suggest providing default implementations and overriding only the Tiger class.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should probably clarify what the teacher means by "without changing" those classes, but I suspect he means "don't change any of the code in those classes, but changing Animal is fine". What I would do is have a counter for the number of Tigers (either as a static data member of Tiger or on the Safari object), add 1 to it in the Tiger constructor, and subtract 1 in the Tiger destructor. Then the countTigers() method could return that value.